# Where are the L3, L4, and L5 points of a hyperbolic orbit?

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

Do the L3, L4, L5 points exist in hyperbolic orbits?  If yes, then where do they lie?

Comment: My guess would be no, because there aren't any points nearby that will be stable.